# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).googlePlaces is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-reviews

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stevenmonson/googleReviews/master/google-places.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/stevenmonson/googleReviews@6e8f0d794393ec657dab69eb1421f3a60add23ef/google-places.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=API_KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>

<div id="google-reviews"> </div>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#google-reviews").googlePlaces({
            placeId: '[Place ID]', 
            render: ['reviews'],
            min-rating: 4,
            max-rows: 5
        });
    });
```

`console.log()` keeps showing the type error, google places is not a function.

Keep changing the cdn version and source link to fix the error but console log still showing the same error.

Comment: Do you include googlePlaces plugin in script tag? googlePlaces is not part of the jQuery you need to include it first.

Comment: Yes, i did add the script tag, and it still showing the error

Comment: Can you show a full code? Best if it's a working example that reproduces the issue. Also, what is googlePlaces you're using, can you share a link to documentation?

Comment: Don't put the code into the comment, edit the question.

Comment: 1. did You defined api key? (key=API_KEY) 2. did You put jquery code inside <script></script> tags?

Comment: In your real code, do you happen to have the jQuery library listed more than once?

Comment: 3. put maps.googleapis.com  script before googleReviews script

Comment: @epascarello, nope

Answer (score 0):

Use scripts in this order:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/google-places-data@0.1.1/google-places.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=Function.prototype&libraries=places&key=YOUR_KEY"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/google-places-data@0.1.1/google-places.css">
```

test on authorized site in Google Cloud/Maps API